# How did I get three Marshal badges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

Today when I logged on Server Fault there were two messages for me, both with the exact same wording:

> You've earned the "Marshal" badge (Raise 500 helpful flags).

And I noticed that the count of gold badges on my profile had increased from 8 to 10.

I guess it was probably not the intention that the Marshal badge gets counted thrice for me. How did this happen?

Comment: Yeah, I've been dormant on SF for six months and I got two gold badges and some silvers out of the blue this week. Not sure what's up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, there was a bug with issuing Marshal and Excavator badges, which affected all sites of Stack Exchange network. It has been fixed by now: the badges are back to normal, but the inbox notifications remaining as the only reminder of the incident. For details, see [Excavator and Marshal badges are being awarded over and over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/280023)

Comment: There is no x3 indication next to the Marshal badge on my profile. But it is still counted three times in the count of badges on my profile.